# Slow MySQL query - how to improve performance

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT `authors`.email, COUNT(articles.id),  SUM(stats.count_stats)
FROM articles
INNER JOIN authors ON articles.id = `authors`.article_id 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT article_id, SUM(count_cited) AS count_stats 
    FROM article_citations_stats 
    GROUP BY article_id) AS stats ON articles.id = stats.article_id
GROUP BY `authors`.email
HAVING SUM(stats.count_stats) > 10
```

Tables:

```
authors has 200 000 rows
articles has 60 000 riws
article_citations_stats has 200 000 rows
```

The query is extremely slow. Any idea on how to improve the performance.

Comment: provide your schema (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`) for each table please

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare. [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: What about the `explain analyze`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a technical question (sorry, that should be in the comment, but as it's my first post I don't have enough points yet): are *authors* allowed to have more *articles* and *articles* to have more *authors*?

From the current definition I can see the PK in the *authors* table on the *id* and the *article_id* is not null. So if:

1. *id* is the *id* of the *author* 
   then every *author* has exactly one *article* (maybe shared with another *author*) and I think you don't need join to the *articles* table, you can just count *articles_id* directly from the *authors* table. You can also directly use it to join with the *stats* table.
2. *id* is just id of the row
   then in fact author can have more *articles* than 1, but then the *authors* table can be huge and it's probably better to redesign it to have *author_id* in the *articles* table. In that approach however you can't have more *authors* for one *article*.
3. it's allowed that many authors have more articles and vice versa, the bridge table would be required here. And then group by using that table. As 1. doesn't allow to have more articles and 2. doesn't allow to have more authors I would go for 3.

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding the following indexes on the tables(if they are not there yet)

```
articles - (id) 
authors - (id,email)
article_citations_stats - (article_id,count_cited)
```

This should speed up your query.

Further more, you can explain what you are trying to do, and we will help you come up with a faster query if possible.

Comment: Thanks Sagi, I am trying to get all authors (email) for those that have more than 10 citations on all articles they published. Also the count of articles.

Comment: I added all indexes (some of those already there), but it is still slow. I am already waiting for 150sec and still processing.

Comment: Create table schema also added

Comment: Can you provide me with input example and expected output ? I don't understand what exactly you are doing, why is the having part outside of the subquery?

Comment: If possible provide sample data also